# Создать несколько клиентов asp.net для WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, клиент-сервер

Нужно создать несколько клиентов asp.net для WCF, различающихся по url. У меня есть классы GetAllMessages SendMessage, для которых есть свой Views. Но как сделать разделение по адресу и позволять им асинхронно работать, допустим в браузере открыто две страницы, один клиент отправляет сообщение, а другой видит все сообщения. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Для реализации чата лучше всего использовать стандартные библиотеки. Попробуйте SignalR (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

Библиотека удобна тем, что в ней уже реализован основной функционал для передачи собщений.